# PowerShell Azure Functions Multi-Tenancy query

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I have written a very simple Azure Function in PowerShell. I have enabled it as multi-tenant which is also fine.

If I wanted to use : *connect-msolOnline* for example (in the PowerShell script) to connect to an office365 service, how could I get the account that you are asked to provide when you access the API which is secured by AzureAD so I can connect to the tenancy with account given .

Being asked to log on when you hit the API is fine (as it is multi-tenancy) but getting that credential to use in the PowerShell script is the problem I am facing.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Looking through documentation of [Connect-MsolService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/connect-msolservice?view=azureadps-1.0), it expects [PSCredential](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/koteshb/2010/02/12/powershell-how-to-create-a-pscredential-object/). For fetching and storing the account name and password you can use App Settings or another option is using Key vault.

Related documentation:

- App settings: [Deploying secrets to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/best-practices-for-deploying-passwords-and-other-sensitive-data-to-aspnet-and-azure#deploying-secrets-to-azure)
- Key Vault: [Getting Started with Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-get-started)

Comment: All very understandable, but how do I get the PSCredetial in the first place from when someone hits the API and logs in ? Storing it is fine (thanks for the info) but how do I get it in the first place ?

Comment: any suggestions anyone ?